# Angular 5 / Node Express each request uses new session

Tags: node.js, angular, express, session, express-session

I am developing an application in Angular 5 which connects to my server in NodeJS.

I add the user in the req.session object after the user is logged in.

When I make a second request from Angular 5 app to retrieve something from the API, the req.session doesn't contain the user and the req.sessionId is always different.

How can I make the session persistent?

Here are the session and cookieParser middlewares:

```
app.use(cookieParser(config.secret))

app.use(session({
    secret: config.secret,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: false
    }
}))
```

Comment: can you show the code where you put the user in the session? Are you using passportjs as a middleware or do you have your own implementation?

Comment: I use passport with local strategy.

Comment: that's good. Passport usually handles the session stuff through the strategies and by serializing and deserializing the user. But therefore you usually have multiple important configuration files that are essential for the cookie stuff. Especially interesting would be the passport file that is given to your app (where user is serialized/deserialized) and your local strategie, that would probably help to find the error

Answer (score 0):

It was a CORS related issue. I needed to include `{ withCredentials: true }` in the http request options in Angular.